# Reporting a user with suspiciously consistent upvotes

Tags: support

Over on Magento SE I was made aware of a user with 3 or 4 upvotes on pretty much every answer. This looks & feels quite exceptional given that our fledgling community suffers from a lack of upvoting in general. Of course, "exceptional" != impossible so I'm hoping someone can help me think about this or get action taken "the right way".

Comment: There is some more information [in the mod-only section of the help center](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/mod-vote-fraud). Otherwise just ask in the Teacher's Lounge in chat.

Answer (score 12):

The best bet would be to flag one of their answers using a custom "Other" moderator flag explaining your suspicion and asking that they investigate the situation.

A moderator will review the flag, user, etc and take any action if it is needed.

Hmm... I didn't realize you were a mod on Magento. There are tools at your disposal to review this and then take action.  The help center on Magento should have some details on how to proceed, but you should also pop into the moderator chat room and we can help if you have questions.

Comment: The confusion comes from the fact that _moderators don't get (empty) diamonds here on the big meta_. IMHO they should get them.

Comment: Could you... post that as its own thread, @yo'?

Comment: @benmarks Has been done before (sorry got no time to look it up now).

Comment: Added my vote right on top of that status-declined tag...